# Is there a way to add elevation data to the geosjon output of queryRenderedFeatures in mapbox gl js?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl

I know you can query elevation data for a specific lon, lat point but I use queryRenderedFeatures to output a geojson file of the feature set.  I would like to have the elevation value for each lon,lat in the geosjon output from queryRenderedFeatures.

Comment: for what country? if you are doing this for the US you can use the USGS elevation API - see this observable - https://observablehq.com/@reyemtm/query-elevations-using-usgs-and-gmrt - you can also use the terrain data from mapbox, and there are probably ten other ways as well

Comment: Thanks.  Yeah I know I can manually add using mapbox but I have to loop through each lon,lat and query the height for that point.  I just wanted to see if there was an automatic way to add it to the existing geojson output.